# Saying or Idiom for 'trying to force a square through a circle'

Tags: translation, idioms

I'm looking for a saying that explains that A and B aren't better or worse, they are simply different. More specifically, that a Japanese way of doing things isn't better or worse [than a western one], but for me [a westerner] doing it the Japanese way will be worse, because I've been educated in such a different manner that it would be like "trying to force a square through a circle".

Any takers?

Comment: Do you want a phrase that means "A and B differ significantly in quality" or "A and B put together looks awkward"?

Comment: 'trying to force a square through a circle' doesn't mean what you're saying in the rest of your question...

Comment: Like others have said I don't think that the idiom's meaning coincides with the meaning you want to convey. Something more along the lines of "It's like forcing a horse to ride a bike."

Answer (score 6):

How about...

「[木]{き}に[竹]{たけ}を[接]{つ}ぐ」?

> It would be like "trying to force a square through a circle".
>   「まるで、木に竹を接ぐようなものだ。」

Sources:
[英辞郎 "square peg in a round hole"](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=square+peg+in+a+round+hole)
[故事ことわざ辞典「木に竹を接ぐ」](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%A8%E3%81%AB%E7%AB%B9%E3%82%92%E6%8E%A5%E3%81%90-471827)

Comment: "Like grafting bamboo to a tree", that's a very clever saying 

Answer (score 3):

We have an established saying, "丸を四角に言いくるめる," which can be literally translated as "(try to) pursuade / convince sb. a circle as a square, and matches up your quote - "trying to force a square through a circle".

There are several variations to "丸を四角に言いくるめる," for examples, "カラスをサギと言いくるめる - insist on a crow as a white heron" and "白を黒と言い張る - insist on white as black.

These expressions are applied to an obstinate or dishonest  person and his / her behavior, because he / she is pushing a wrong and illogical assertion on others.

Answer (score 1):

```
        We need a [Proverb] tag!
```

I can't think of a nice, colorful Jp expression for [ A and B aren't better or worse, they are simply different.] -- like comparing apples and oranges.

比較のしょうがない

比較してもしょうがない

---

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole　　　　"Square peg in a round hole" is an idiomatic expression which describes the unusual individualist who could not fit into a niche of his or her society.

As for an [eccentric maverick], I can't think of a colorful Jp expression or proverb either.

http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=maverick

> maverick figure  《a ～》 　　型破りな［わが道を行くタイプの］人物
>
> 異端児　　　一匹オオカミ　　　　　　独立独行の、型破りの